# Windows Automatic Update Installer

Tags: windows, updates, windows-update

Is there a way to have a program install windows updates and then reboot and install and reboot automatically all night long?

It would shave a lot of time off my hands.

All versions of Windows.

Comment: Please specify the OS version.

Comment: All versions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at http://download.wsusoffline.net/ as this will allow you to download all the updates and then you can install all the updates at once. This should reduce the number of reboot and has the added advantage of only have to download all the patches once.

You can add this to startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Another Client could be http://www.wuinstall.com/index.php/en/free
You could write a short script which Downloads all Updates and after that install all updates.